# Z87N-WiFi message "Unknown display" Howto fix?

Tags: intel-graphics, display-resolution

I have just built myself a mini-itx rig

- Motherboard = Gigabyte GAZ87-wifi
- Graphics = inbuilt HD4600
- 21" inch Iiyama monitor VGA connected via VGA to DVI convertor

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. The graphics resolution is pretty low. Because the graphics is identified as "Unknown Display", I am unable to change the resolution.

I have installed Linux Graphics drivers from Intel as below:

[Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.5 for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux)

This has made no difference and I still have the message "Unknown Display"

Any suggestions?